# FirebaseListObservable Observable Children

Tags: observable, angularfire2, lifecycle-hook

I have this code currently:

```
<div class="ui segment" *ngFor="let message of models | async">
  <team-message [model]="message" [users]="users" (onReply)="handleMessageReply($event)"></team-message>
</div>
```

In testing I've noticed that any change to a message causes the affected `team-message` component to be re-rendered. I currently have a collapsible `Replies` section within each `team-message` component that is closing everytime a user submits a reply -- collapsed is the default state -- and I do not want that to occur.

I was under the impression that this smart component/dumb(ish) component approach should not cause my 'touched' `team-message` component to consistently re-render, but yet, it does.

Is there any way for me to prevent this Lifecycle Hook from getting called again, or to pass the reply open/closed state to the subsequent component?